# On what basis 'Exist()' method(in QTP) will identify existence of a test object in the open Application?

Tags: automation, qtp

On what basis does the `Exist()` method(in QTP) identify existence of a test object in the open Application?

Answer (score 3):

QTP will try to match the description of the test object to a control in your application.

HP published a blog post about how [QTP identifies objects](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/09/20/how-uft-identifies-objects/) which goes a bit into what `Exist` does and the (unexpected) side effect that you **must not** call `Exist` on a test object returned from `ChildObjects`.